# Javascript Cannot split "-" character

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split `"2011 – June 2015"`

```
var dates = "2011 – June 2015"

dates.split(" - ")
```

OR

```
dates.split("-")
```

is returning `["2011 – June 2015"]`

However, `dates.split(" ")` works as expected

Is there something unique about the `-` character? I tried escaping it but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: `–` is an EN dash, not a hyphen. run `"–"=="-"` in your console.

Comment: ahh, any suggestion on how to split on it?

Comment: @MorganAllen use an en dash ? `dates.split(" – ")`

Comment: I cant believe I'm asking this, what character is that on my keyboard

Comment: @MorganAllen its the hyphen

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes there are unicode points and alt-codes

Comment: lol, why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: *Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.* [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MorganAllen If you're using a Mac, it's `Alt`+`-` for an EN dash and `Alt`+`Shift`+`-` for an EM dash. Not sure about other systems.

Comment: so this is getting downvoted because I wasn't aware of the difference between an EN dash and hyphen? I had no idea there was such a thing as an EN dash up until this point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dates are split by an En dash, which is not the same as a hyphen so it will not split.

```js
console.log(
  "2011 – June 2015".split(' – '), // en dash 
)

console.log(
  "2011 – June 2015".split(' - '), // hyphen 
)
```

Comment: I copied pasted that and it worked. I tried the `(' -- ')` but that didn't seem to work. How do I make the mdash?

Comment: I just copy pasted the character into the above code.

Comment: oooh good call. ok. Yea, did the same and it worked :-) I will mark the answer as right when I can.

Answer (score 3):

You can split on all 3 of the common dashes (hyphen [short], endash [width of a `n`], emdash [width of an `m`] with a regex:

```js
console.log(
  "2011 – June 2015".split(/[\-–—]/)
)
```